# How to use Advanced Symbology in ArcGIS for Android?

Tags: arcgis-server, java, arcgis-android

I try to use the advanced symbology in order to draw nato symbols in JAVA
I need little help about it,

1. What the parameters _WKID mean like in this command : lmessage.setProperty("_WKID", "3857");
2. What the parameter UniqueDesignation mean?
3. THE MOST IMPORTENT QUESTION: How can send parameters to symboles llike the symbole "Target" (TACGRP.FSUPP.PNT.TGT.PTGT) (2.X.4.1.1.1) with sic G*FPPTS---****X
   parameters like "Target Alt" , "Description" and "Name"?

Comment: Which ArcGIS product and version are you using?

Comment: ARCGIS for android 2.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I responded to your post on the ArcGIS forum [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/84363-Using-Advanced-Symbology?p=300621&posted=1#post300621).

For general information about NATO military symbology, the [APP-61 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_Military_Symbols_for_Land_Based_Systems) is a good introduction.

Comment: I updated the forum [post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/84363-Using-Advanced-Symbology?p=308181#post308181) to address your additional question.